# FormArray in dynamic form angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, form-control

I have implemented a stackblitz where you can create a dynamic form using some configuration. Everything works fine till you use a `FormArray`. What's the idea? Basically you can have many fields in your configuration file with different type. For example `checkbox`, `text`, `number` `select` etc. In some case you should have a more complex structure and so you should have a `FormArray`. In this stackblitz I tried to represent what's going on

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder-gycshd?file=app/dynamic-form-builder/dynamic-form-builder.component.ts

So, when I found an `array` type I'm going to create a FormArray instead of a simple `FormControl` that's my list of fields

```
 public fields: any[] = [
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "firstName",
      label: "First Name",
      required: true
    },
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "lastName",
      label: "Last Name",
      required: true
    },
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "email",
      label: "Email",
      required: true
    },
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "description",
      label: "Description",
      required: true,
      multiLine: true
    },
    {
      type: "dropdown",
      name: "country",
      label: "Country",
      value: "in",
      required: true,
      options: [{ value: "in", label: "India" }, { value: "us", label: "USA" }]
    },
    {
      type: "array",
      name: "users",
      label: "Users",
      structure: "users.json"
    }
  ];
```

And here's my dynamic form builder component

```
export class DynamicFormBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() fields: any[] = [];
  form: FormGroup;
  allDatas: any;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let fieldsCtrls = {};
    this.allDatas = getData();
    for (let f of this.fields) {
      if (f.type != "array") {
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormControl(
          this.allDatas[f.name] || "",
          Validators.required
        );
      } else {
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormArray([
          new FormControl(this.allDatas[f.name] || "", Validators.required)
        ]);
      }
    }
    this.form = new FormGroup(fieldsCtrls);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I set a value from allDatas, if exists, and I create the FormGroup with FormControls and FormArray. But when I generate the `arraybox` I have errors. This is the arraybox component that displays a FormArray control:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { ConfigService } from "../../config.service";

@Component({
  selector: "arraybox",
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="form">
      <div formArrayName="{{ field.name }}">
        <div
          *ngFor="let obj of arrayFileds; index as idx"
          [formGroupName]="idx"
        >
          <input
            attr.type="{{ obj.type }}"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="{{ obj.name }}"
            id="{{ obj.name }}"
            name="{{ obj.name }}"
            formControlName="{{ idx }}"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ArrayBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() field: any = {};
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  arrayFileds: any = [];

  get isValid() {
    return this.form.controls[this.field.name].valid;
  }
  get isDirty() {
    return this.form.controls[this.field.name].dirty;
  }

  constructor(private config: ConfigService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.arrayFileds = this.config.getData(this.field.structure);
    console.log(this.arrayFileds);
  }
}
```

getData() returns the structure of that FormArray. In this case

```
[{
    "label": "Username",
    "name": "userName",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "label": "User email",
    "name": "userEmail",
    "type": "text"
}]
```

The errors in console are:

```
ERROR
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'users -> 0 -> 0'
ERROR
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'users -> 1'
```

I really don't know what's wrong here. How can I use FormArray to show the fields with their values in this form?

NB. stackblitz gets me an error if I use http to parse json so for now I'm using directly an import of the json. Basically, `this.field.structure` in this example is not used (but it should be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, nice work but you need to change a few things to achieve what you want.

1. You need to change how you initialize the form array. You have named controls in your `FormArray` so you need to push `FormGroup` into your `FormArray` :

```
 for (let f of this.fields) {
      if (f.type != "array") {
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormControl(
          this.allDatas[f.name] || "",
          Validators.required
        );
      } else { // changed part
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormArray([
          ...this.allDatas[f.name].map(
            r =>
              new FormGroup(
                Object.entries(r).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
                  acc[k] = new FormControl(v || "", Validators.required);
                  return acc;
                }, {})
              )
          )
        ]);
      }
```

The above code basically generates `FormGroup` that has the object keys as `FormControls`

2. You need to change your `ArrayBox` components template like below :

```
 <input
            attr.type="{{ obj.type }}"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="{{ obj.name }}"
            id="{{ obj.name }}"
            name="{{ obj.name }}"
            formControlName="{{ obj.name }}"
          />
```

You had `formControlName="{{ idx }}"` which will cause Angular to seek a `FormControl` named `0 1` that's one of the reasons why you get `Error: Cannot find control with path: 'users -> 0 -> 0'` error. The other reason is you were adding directly `FormControl`s instead `FormGroup`s. As your `ArrayBox` template states `FormArray` has an array of `FormGroup`

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder-yr3zv9?file=app/dynamic-form-builder/atoms/arraybox.ts)

As @End.Game noticed the array part still had some parts to fix. The root cause of the problem lies in the `ArrayBox` template. You were iterating over your configuration objects to render your form. But since it's a `FormArray` you also need to repeat that template for the count of the `FormArray`. So you will need another `*ngFor` to achieve that :

```
   <div [formGroup]="form">
      <div formArrayName="{{ field.name }}">
        <div *ngFor="let frm of formArray.controls; index as idx">
          <div formGroupName="{{ idx }}">
            <div *ngFor="let obj of arrayFileds;">
              <input
                attr.type="{{ obj.type }}"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="{{ obj.name }}"
                id="{{ obj.name }}"
                name="{{ obj.name }}"
                formControlName="{{ obj.name }}"
              />
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Please also note that moved `idx` variable to the parent loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your example it's working, in part. I mean, It's ok and it goes as I want, but it shows only one result. I can only see { userName: "Second test", userEmail: "secondEmail@test.com" } and not the first one. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @End.Game I noticed that now. Will update the question and stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Check this `stackblitz` example:-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-creation

hope it will be useful for you !

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for. This example creates FormControl only. Not FormArray